# How to load js from url inside script tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code like this:

```
 <script>

if(/iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  <script src="http://****/iphone.js"></script>
  } else { 
  <script src="http://****/sp.js"></script>
  } 
</script>
```

does not work well. how to load?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: @smerny 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Comment: Loading the script is in there too...

Comment: You could easily do it via server side technologies, but not easily via client side.

Comment: "does not work well" is too ambiguous. Please post how it is not working.